# Need to conditionally join on one of the two columns(whichever exists)

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I am writing a sas macro, where I am trying to join to one of the two columns whichever exists. But when I give something like this it errors out, since it wants both the columns to exist:

```
%Macro Base_pop(ssc,input_table,POPN_TBL);

PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE test_&ssc. AS 
        SELECT B.ACCOUNT_ID 
        FROM ADL_EXT.&input_table.TB  INNER JOIN
             ADL_BSE.BRDM_POP_FLG_&POPN_TBL.B
             ON B.ACCOUNT_ID = (CASE WHEN %sysfunc(exist(TB.ACCOUNT_ID)) then TB.ACCOUNT_ID
                                     ELSE TB.FAC_ID                                                                       
                                END)
        WHERE B.FLG = 'Y'
        ORDER BY B.ACCOUNT_ID ;

QUIT;

%MEND;
```

The code errors out saying TB.Account_id does not exist. I tried coalesce as well, that did not work too.

Only one of the two columns would exist on the tables passed to the macro.
So, I need to dynamically join on the column that exists in my current table.

Suggestions please!

Comment: 1) The EXIST() function is testing for the existence of a dataset, not of a variable. (2) Since you made a macro you can use %IF logic to conditionally generate the SAS code you want to run. That way you can NOT generate any references to variables that do not exist.  Your example does not have any conditionally generated code. I suspect that you want to replace the CASE statement with %IF.. %THEN %ELSE statement.

Comment: Can't you just have the programmer that is calling the macro tell the macro what variable name to use?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tom! The macro is big and uses various columns which could be existing for several tables and not for others. Even after the conditional %if logic is false, why does the compiler look for variable names that follow a false condition. It's not just this one column , i have several such columns, don't want to keep adding parameters, don't we have a work around.

Comment: Also, what should I give in %if %then logic? I need to check if the table referenced by the alias TB has account_id then utilize it else join on facility_id. The moment I refer to Account_id, it abends.

Comment: It is too late once the SQL statement is running to test for variable's existence, even if you could. You need to first test and then generate the code using the variable you want to use. See answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description says that you want to test for the existence of variables, but you did not include any code to do that.  One way to make that test is to query the SAS metadata about the table.  So this code below will take the first name, either ACCOUNT_ID or FAC_ID, that it finds in the input dataset and use that. If none are found then it writes an error message to the SAS log.

```
%macro base_pop(ssc,input_table,popn_tbl);
%local out ina inb var ;
%let out=test_&ssc ;
%let ina=%upcase(adl_ext.&input_table);
%let inb=%upcase(adl_bse.brdm_pop_flg_&popn_tbl);

proc sql noprint ;
  select name into :var
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname = "%scan(&ina,1,.)"
      and memname="%scan(&ina,2,.)"
      and upcase(name) in ('ACCOUNT_ID','FAC_ID')
  ;
%if (&sqlobs) %then %do;
  create table &out as
    select b.account_id
    from &ina a inner join &inb b
    on b.account_id = a.&var
    where b.flg = 'y'
    order by b.account_id
  ;
%end;
%else %put ERROR: Could not find either ACCOUNT_ID or FAC_ID in &ina ;

quit;

%mend base_pop;
```

Comment: Thanks Tom ! But like I had mentioned, I have several such checks in the code, to conditionally join on columns that exist. Dont want to go looking and then creating macro variables for all of them, I'd rather pass them as macro variables then. Need to make the code quicker and efficient.